# How do I make my nav list go inside of the sidebar hamburger menu?

Tags: html, css, hamburger-menu

[this](https://codepen.io/niavonartworks/pen/dyPmeWx) is what I have so far.

```html
<div class="header-wrapper-sticky">
  <nav class="navicon">
    <button class="hamburger-menu">
      <span class="top"></span>
      <span class="middle"></span>
      <span class="bottom"></span>
    </button>

    <ul class="navlist">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Crystal Directory</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

How I could **flip/reverse** the hamburger menu so that it faces left and how do I make the navlist go inside of the hamburger menu so that when its clicked it will come out of the side?

Comment: you should try with jquery toggle concept

Comment: Give a try in bootstrap , you can not transfer one ul to other div . you have to create another list inside your humburger and make it block when clicked and hide other as per screen size.